# How to deal with Final Strings?

Tags: java, string, types

Is there any advantage of making `String as final` or can we make `String as final` ?, my understanding is that as String is immutable, there is no point of making it final, is this correct or they are situation where one would want to make `String as Final` ?

Code:

```
private final String a = "test";

or 

private String b = "test";
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`final` means that the reference can never change. `String` immutability  means something different; it means when a `String` is created (value, not reference, i.e: "text"), it can't be changed.

For example:

```
String x = "Strings Are ";
String s = x;
```

Now s and x both reference the same `String`. However:

```
x += " Immutable Objects!";
System.out.println("x = " + x);
System.out.println("s = " + s);
```

This will print:

```
x = Strings Are Immutable Objects
s = Strings Are
```

This proves that any `String` created cannot be changed, and when any change does happen, a new `String` gets created.

Now, for `final`, if we declare x as `final` and try to change its value, we'll get an exception:

```
final String x = "Strings Are ";
x += " Immutable Objects!";
```

Here is the exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot assign a value to final variable x
```

Answer (score 4):

It means that that *variable* can never even point to a different string.

(And yes, a String object is immutable... but a variable could point to a different instance of String. Unless it's final.)

(edit -- in your example, you didnt name your variable...

```
final String x = "test";
```

)

Comment: What does it actually mean by saying String is immutable, I was under the impression that its value cannot be changed and same is the function of final keyword, is my understanding not right  ?

Comment: It means that you can say x = "this"; and x = "that", but there's no method like x.setValue("new string");.

Answer (score 4):

final means that the reference cannot change, not the value. Regardless of the final, Strings are always immutable.

```
final String a = "test";
String b = "hello";

a = "world"; // error, a can't change reference to the String object "world"
b = "two"; // ok, b points to a different String object "two"
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifier `final` means that variable cannot be changed.

```java
final String s = "abcd";

// later in the code
s = "efgh";  // This will not compile
```

*Immutable* means that there is no such method available in the `String` class which allow to change its contents, e.g. `setter`, `append`, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "there is no method on `String`"?

Answer (score 0):

All fine here, but there are two more ways to "**deal with Final Strings**", as you put it, but in terms of 'where to place them':

1. Create an interface that includes final static variables (and final Strings) and implement it wherever you need them, and
2. Create a class for constants and make a static import.

Way 1, was popular some 10 years ago, and may still be where you have large collections of final variables. 
Way 2, is simple to use but a little weird, since you can refer to constants without qualification, which makes your code difficult to comprehend.

Answer (score 0):

One difference in having a final field, is that because String is immutable, it may as well be static.

```
private final String a = "test";
```

slightly more efficient, possibly clearer as

```
private static final String a = "test";
```